# How can I iterate through Alchemy CMS elements in Rails View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, alchemyapi

I am trying to iterate over an element called vacation_date.  However, I keep getting the error:

undefined local variable or method `element' for #<#:0x007fa394a33948>

```
 <h2 class="no-margin-top">Vacation Dates</h2>
    <%= render_elements :only => [:vacation_date] %>
      <ul>
        <% element.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
           <li><%= tag.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

How can I iterate over this element in the html.erb file?
I can render all of the elements by calling just

```
   <%= render_elements :only => [:vacation_date] %>
```

and deleting the rest of the code.  However, Id like to be able to iterate over all vacation dates.

Answer (score 0):

use `render_element` like it's described here https://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_cms/blob/b712ac2fc9fdc3cb6786b1c6733f8d37be4c2588/app/helpers/alchemy/elements_helper.rb#L98-L172